# run a compiled java file with command line using an input file on a certain condition

Tags: java, command-line

I want to run a java file through the command line. Sometimes I want to run it with an input file and sometimes I want to run it without an input file.

For example, I have a java file named `Main`.
Can I achieve something like the following?

```
boolean fileExists;
if(fileExists)
   java Main < input.txt
else
   java Main
```

Comment: Create a simple batch file or shell script to check whether the file exists and to start your program.

Comment: I suggest adding the file name as a [command-line argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) and in the java code check whether the file exists.

Comment: Of course that is possible. But your question isnt clear. Do you want to do that with Java, or are you asking how to do that for windows batch files, or linux shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you can use:

```
IF EXIST input.txt (java Main < input.txt) ELSE (java Main)
```

Note: Don't forget to add parentheses `()` or the system won't read else command.

Comment: You might want to say that this is pseudo code.

Comment: I answer it using the Windows command line.